Proving $P(X<1+ \frac{1}{n})=1$ for non-negative random variable $X$ ans $E(x^n) \leq K$
Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable and suppose that there is $K>0$ such that for all $n \geq 1$ we have $E(X^n) \leq K$.
a) Show that for any $n \geq 1$ we have $P(X<1+ \frac{1}{n})=1$
b) Show that $P(X \leq 1)=1$
Attempt: I have initiated the problem using Markov's inequality where i got:
$P(X<1+ \frac{1}{n}) \geq 1- \frac{k}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$. after that I don't understand how to get the inequality.

yeah, sorry for the typo, I have fixed it

Markov's inequality is a good idea, just take it one step farther. Let $n\geq 1$. Then for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$:
$\mathbb{P}(X\geq 1+\frac{1}{n})=\mathbb{P}(X^m\geq (1+\frac{1}{n})^m)\leq\frac{E[X^m]}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^m}.$
Can you finish from here?

but I can't understand how to deduce $P(X<1+ \frac{1}{n})=1$

@Tas I hope it's clear that my approach is showing the equivalent statement $\mathbb{P}(X\geq 1+\frac{1}{n})=0$. Hint: Take $m\to\infty$.
